# Select distinct by two properties in a list

Tags: c#, list, distinct, linq-to-objects

I have a `list<message>` that contains properties of type `Guid` and `DateTime` (as well as other properties). I would like to get rid of all of the items in that list where the `Guid` and `DateTime` are the same (except one). There will be times when those two properties will be the same as other items in the list, but the other properties will be different, so I can't just use `.Distinct()`

```
List<Message> messages = GetList();
//The list now contains many objects, it is ordered by the DateTime property

messages = from p in messages.Distinct(  what goes here? );
```

This is what I have right now, but it seems like there ought to be a better way

```
List<Message> messages = GetList();

for(int i = 0; i < messages.Count() - 1)  //use Messages.Count() -1 because the last one has nothing after it to compare to
{
    if(messages[i].id == messages[i+1}.id && messages[i].date == message[i+1].date)
    {
        messages.RemoveAt(i+1);
    {
    else
    {
         i++
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I couldn't find that when I searched.

Comment: I'm glad Jon's answer worked for you. Just a note of caution: your "currently used method" doesn't compile, and (after fixing the compile errors) it will not work in all cases - depending on the order of your elements, you'd get different **(wrong)** results (after all, you're only comparing adjacent elements with each other).

Comment: thanks for the heads-up.  GetList() returns an ordered List.  I've tested different cases, and I get the result I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

LINQ to Objects doesn't provide this functionality easily in a built-in way, but [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) has a handy `DistinctBy` method:

```
messages = messages.DistinctBy(m => new { m.id, m.date }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm assuming MoreLINQ is free to use?  I don't see that explicitly written anywhere on the page.

Comment: @user1304444: It's an open source library - see the "Apache License 2.0" link on the left of the page.

Comment: For anyone else viewing this question, the link Shyju mentioned above seems to be a great answer also.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Comment: @user1304444: Yeah, I think it was around the time of writing that answer that I decided to start MoreLINQ :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Does this perform an 'either' property is distinct or 'together' (treating both as one property) they are distinct?

Comment: @PaulZahra: Together. Two items a and b will only be seen as equal if `a.id == b.id && a.date == b.date`.

Comment: Having discovered this answer, I now cannot live without `DistinctBy`!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/e384ba07f13d7fd15609da5348dbf4523f93c1e1/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs#L65) is the source code of the `DistinctBy` method. It is small and copy-pastable.

Comment: [This is now available in .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) without needing a third-party dependency or custom extension method!

Comment: With [tuple literal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/#tuples) introduced in C# 7.0 (.NET Framework 4.7), you can replace this anonymous type with [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples): `DistinctBy(m => (m.id, m.date))`

Answer (score 21):

Jon Skeet's `DistinctBy` is definitely the way to go, however if you are interested in defining your own extension method you might take fancy in this more concise version:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var known = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(element => known.Add(keySelector(element)));
}
```

which has the same signature:

```
messages = messages.DistinctBy(x => new { x.id, x.date }).ToList();
```

Comment: I know this is old, but please note that you have to call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` after calling `DistinctBy()`. If you work directly on the `IEnumerable` and enumerate it multiple times it won't work, since the items are added to the `HashSet` while going through the `IEnumerable` the first time and won't be returned a second time, as shown in this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5PUJxl).

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 var messages = (from g1 in messages.GroupBy(s => s.id) from g2 in g1.GroupBy(s => s.date) select g2.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my [PowerfulExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerfulExtensions/) library. Currently it's in a very young stage, but already you can use methods like Distinct, Union, Intersect, Except on any number of properties;

This is how you use it:

```
using PowerfulExtensions.Linq;
...
var distinct = myArray.Distinct(x => x.A, x => x.B);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var messages = messages
               .GroupBy(m => m.id)
               .GroupBy(m => m.date)
               .Select(m => m.First());
```

Comment: does not compile... Remember that GroupBy returns an `IGrouping`.

Comment: This approach is valid if HashSet<T> is not available on the plateform you are developing like silverslight ....