# DistinctBy with two properties in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, morelinq

Looking at [Select distinct by two properties in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811110/c-sharp-select-distinct-by-two-properties-in-a-list) it is possible to use the DistinctBy extensionmethod with two properties. I tried to convert this to vb.net, but I'm not getting the expected results

Test Class:

```
Public Class Test
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Id & " - " & Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Test Method:

```
Private Sub RunTest()
    Dim TestList As New List(Of Test)

    TestList.Add(New Test() With {.Id = 1, .Name = "A"})
    TestList.Add(New Test() With {.Id = 2, .Name = "A"})
    TestList.Add(New Test() With {.Id = 3, .Name = "A"})
    TestList.Add(New Test() With {.Id = 1, .Name = "A"})
    TestList.Add(New Test() With {.Id = 1, .Name = "B"})
    TestList.Add(New Test() With {.Id = 1, .Name = "A"})

    Dim Result As IEnumerable(Of Test)

    Result = TestList.DistinctBy(Function(element) element.Id)
    '1 - A
    '2 - A
    '3 - A

    Result = TestList.DistinctBy(Function(element) element.Name)
    '1 - A
    '1 - B

    Result = TestList.DistinctBy(Function(element) New With {element.Id, element.Name})
    '1 - A
    '2 - A
    '3 - A
    '1 - A
    '1 - B
    '1 - A

    'Expected:
    '1 - A
    '2 - A
    '3 - A
    '1 - B
End Sub
```

Is this at all possible in vb.net using anonymous types?
Doing something like this:

```
Result = TestList.DistinctBy(Function(element) element.Id & "-" & element.Name)
```

is working, therefore I'm guessing I'm missing something with equality in anonymous types here.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Your code should work just fine.

Comment: Yes. You need to add Key before properties to compare two anonymous type instances for equality.

Comment: See the documentation for anonymous types in VB for more details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek The code is working fine, yes. But the last Result is different from what I'm looking for (both outputs are in the code above). Using the Key-Keyword is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `Key` before property. like

`New With {Key element.Id, Key element.Name}` in VB.

So,

```
Result = TestList.DistinctBy(Function(element) New With {Key element.Id, Key element.Name})
```

See the documentation for [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) in VB for more details.