# How to Distinct List<OrderDetails> based on one values from OrderDetails

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have order details:

```
public class OrderDetails
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
       // [DataMember]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now if I do a distinct like below , it returns everything:

```
List<OrderDetails> orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();
---------------------------------
return orderDetails.Distinct();
```

But if I do distinct like :

```
  List<OrderDetails> orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();
    ---------------------------------
return orderDetails.Select(x => x.OrderId).Distinct();
```

Then I get only Order Ids.

How can I get the Distinct Orderdetails(both OrderID and ProductId)  based on OrderId

Comment: Use `.Where(x => x.OrderId == 4)`

Comment: `.Select` will return only selected member so use `where`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload of [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` as comparer.

You can define it as:

```
public class OrderDetailsEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<OrderDetails>
{
    public bool Equals(OrderDetails x, OrderDetails y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (x.OrderId == y.OrderId );
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
    {
        return obj.OrderId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
var osrderedOrderDetails =
       orderDetails.Distinct(new OrderDetailsEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: You can also implement equals and GetHashCode on the class itself

Comment: @Aron, I think it is not good idea. In this case you are define the equality relation between the entities at all which can be not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Distinct with `OrderId`

```
return orderDetails.GroupBy(x => x.OrderId).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Distinct with `OrderId` and `ProductId`

```
return orderDetails.GroupBy(x => new {x.OrderId, x.ProductId}).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: How is this workin for you??? .Disinct expects a IEquator and you are passing a func !!!

Comment: First GroupBy with property which you want distinct result and after that select first item of group.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811110/c-sharp-select-distinct-by-two-properties-in-a-list SO link. There is a library moreLINQ which has DistinctBy method.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that takes an `Order Id`, and return the list as below...

```
public List<OrderDetails> GetDistinctOrderDetails(int orderId)
{
  List<OrderDetails> orderDetails = GetAllOrders();
  return orderDetails.Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId).Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return orderdetails.Where(a=>a.OrderID == _inputvalue).ToArray();
```

"toarray" can be any of the collection types what ever you need 
unless your function returns Ienumerable<> then you don't need it

using distinct() is not a good idea as it will drop rows

Answer (score 0):

Implement IEquatable interface:

```
public class OrderDetails : IEquatable<OrderDetails>
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(OrderDetails anotherOrder)
    {
        return this.OrderId.Equals(anotherOrder.OrderId);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.OrderId;
    }
}
```

Now, try orderDetails.Distinct();