# morelinq distinct by multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2013, distinct-values, morelinq

I have been using morelinq to create a distinct list of objects. My objects have about 20 properties, none of which will be unique in the final list. 
However 2 properties used together can reveal the unique objects:

Parent Id | Child Id

- 1      |      1
- 1      |      2
- 2      |      1
- 2      |      2
- 2      |      3

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811110/select-distinct-by-two-properties-in-a-list) and thought it was the same problem so I downloaded morelinq and tried using:

```
list = list.DistinctBy(c => new { c.id, c.parentid }).ToList();
```

However this results in a distinct list on EITHER property, not both (so I'd only ever see one child per parent)

What is the correct way to use morelinq to achieve this?

Comment: Use Groupby instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    list = list
           .GroupBy(a=> new { a.id, a.parentid})
           .Select(a=> a.first());
```