# How to remove duplicates from a list of custom objects, by a property of the object

Tags: c#, linq, list, object, duplicates

I want to remove the duplicates based on a property of my object:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string _prop1;
    public string _prop2;

    public LocationsClass(string prop1, string prop2)
    {
        _prop1= prop1;
        _prop2= prop2;
    }
}

...

List<MyType> myList;
```

So basically I want to remove all MyType objects from myList, with the same value in _prop1. Is there a way to do this, probably with LINQ?

Comment: Linq will just get you a filtered list. It will not modify your original myList object - just making sure your expectation is right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811110/select-distinct-by-two-properties-in-a-list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-by-linq

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var distinctItems = myList.GroupBy(x => x.prop1).Select(y => y.First());
```

Comment: For smaller collection it is ok to use GroupBy. In other case it should be used with a grain of salt, it creates time complexity and could affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) [DistinctBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs):

```
distinctItems = myList.DistinctBy(x => x.prop1).ToList();
```

or with several properties:

```
distinctItems = myList.DistinctBy(x=> new { x.prop1, x.prop2}).ToList();
```