# Filtering duplicates from a type collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, duplicates, filtering

I'm filtering a list by grouping on two parameters and selecting the most recent type in the sub-grouplist based on createdate (using first()).
This eliminates the duplicates on the x.application and x.externalid properties.

```
var list = ((List<SomeType>)xDic)
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.Application, x.ExternalID})
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.First().CreateDate)
            .Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
```

What I am having trouble with is defining yet another combination of properties (x.application and x.externaldisplayid) to filter with and group by to take the first one.

To summarize, I need to get a unique List of SomeTypes by filtering out any duplicates based on the ((x.application/x.externalid) OR (x.application/x.externaldisplayid)) combinations.

```
Example set:
{ "extID": 1234, "extDspID" : 111, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 2/01/2015}
{ "extID": 1234, "extDspID" : 5, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 1/01/2015}
{ "extID": 012, "extDspID" : 90, "App" : "Mono", "CreateDate": 6/06/2015}
{ "extID": 999, "extDspID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/08/2015}
{ "extID": 333, "extDspID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/12/2015}
{ "extID": 345, "extDspID" : 33, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 2/01/2015}
{ "extID": 666, "extDspID" : 33, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 1/01/2015}

desired result:
{ "extID": 1234, "extDspID" : 111, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 2/01/2015}
{ "extID": 012, "extDspID" : 90, "App" : "Mono", "CreateDate": 6/06/2015}
{ "extID": 333, "extDspID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/12/2015}
{ "extID": 345, "extDspID" : 33, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 2/01/2015}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. Can you provide the definition of your class (`SomeType`)?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811110/select-distinct-by-two-properties-in-a-list (but not completely sure)

Comment: `public class SomeType
    {
        public string ExternalDisplayId { get; set; }
        public string ExternalID { get; set; }
        public string Application { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Is "Distinct" in your future? My situation does differ, but this might give you an idea:
List<String> ItemDescs = _itemsForMonthYearList.Select(x => x.ItemDescription).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I am achieving the same result as a distictby(). The tricky part is defining an additional property set to define the uniqueness and filter on it further.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - I have to account for the most recent createdate dimension, so the distinct doesn't address my problem fully.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what does `((x.application/x.externalid) OR (x.application/x.externaldisplayid)) combinations` mean?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what does `.OrderByDescending(z => z.First().CreateDate)` do? Why are you choosing some random item from the group? Is `xDic` already sorted?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - I need to filter out all duplicates in the List<SomeType> based on a combination of properties:
Delete all type duplicates that have the same values for it's Application and ExternalID properties.
Secondly, Delete all remaining type duplicates that have the same values for it's Application and ExternalDisplayID properties.

Comment: What about ordering?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I need to keep the object - in the event of duplicates - that has the most recent createdate.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - I find duplicates based on a combination(2) of properties. Externalid and externaldisplayid will have different values. I have to find matched combinations with those two properties in each scenario. (application and externalid ) or (application and externaldisplayid)

Comment: I suspect that the fact you can't explain what you want is the problem :)  Are all 3 of these duplicates {A1,id1,disp1}, {A1,id1,disp2}, {A1,id2,disp2}?

Comment: There are way too many similar questions to this on SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -
{ "extID": 1234, "extDID" : 111, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 2/1/2015}
{ "extID": 1234, "extDID" : 5, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 1/1/2015}
{ "extID": 012, "extDID" : 90, "App" : "Mono", "CreateDate": 6/6/2015}
{ "extID": 999, "extDID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/8/2015}
{ "extID": 333, "extDID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/12/2015}

result:
{ "extID": 1234, "extDID" : 111, "App" : "Test", "CreateDate": 2/1/2015}
{ "extID": 012, "extDID" : 90, "App" : "Mono", "CreateDate": 6/6/2015}
{ "extID": 333, "extDID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/12/2015}

Comment: sorry for the formatting. copy paste and carriage return on each "}" :)

Comment: Can you please edit your post showing an example of duplicates?

Comment: @ataravati - please direct me in the way to fashion my search terms in order to find appropriate search results and not waste any of your precious time.

Comment: Are you sure the third item in the desired result set should be { "extID": 333, "extDspID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/12/2015}?

Comment: @BenSmith - yes since it has the most recent createdate out of the two:
{ "extID": 999, "extDspID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/08/2015}
{ "extID": 333, "extDspID" : 78, "App" : "Epic", "CreateDate": 8/12/2015}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, declare two equality compareres to specify your two conditions like this:

```
public class MyEqualityComparer1 : IEqualityComparer<SomeType>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeType x, SomeType y)
    {
        return x.Application == y.Application && x.ExternalID == y.ExternalID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeType obj)
    {
        return (obj.Application + obj.ExternalID).GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class MyEqualityComparer2 : IEqualityComparer<SomeType>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeType x, SomeType y)
    {
        return x.Application == y.Application && x.ExternalDisplayId == y.ExternalDisplayId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeType obj)
    {
        return (obj.Application + obj.ExternalDisplayId).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then, order your list by `CreatedDate` and then use `Distinct` to filter your list like this:

```
var result = xDic
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
    .Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer1())
    .Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer2());
```

The `Distinct` method [should remove the later items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734852/does-c-sharp-distinct-method-keep-original-ordering-of-sequence-intact), so we should be able to depend on the fact that we used `OrderByDescending` to make sure that `Distinct` will remove items with the less recent `CreatedTime`.

However, since the documentation of `Distinct` do not guarantee this, you can use a custom distinct method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderedDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        HashSet<T> hash_set = new HashSet<T>(comparer);

        foreach(var item in enumerable)
            if (hash_set.Add(item))
                yield return item;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var result = xDic
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
    .OrderedDistinct(new MyEqualityComparer1())
    .OrderedDistinct(new MyEqualityComparer2());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Yacoub. I will try it as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: Interesting - does  `Distinct(x => {x.p1}).Distinct(x=>{x.p2})` give the same result as `Distinct(x => {x.p2}).Distinct(x=>{x.p1})` (which should be true for what OP is looking for).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Yes. All duplicates are removed and this is guaranteed by invoking the two `Distinct` operation (regardless of the order of invocation). The only thing that remains is to make sure that we always delete the least recent item. Since we order the list, we are sure that any item that is removed by any of the `Distinct` operations has a similar item earlier in the sequence with a more recent `CreatedDate`.

Answer (score 0):

The current accepted answer will not sort your "SomeType" objects correctly and so won't produce your desired result set.

I've implemented a solution here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qBkIXo

I too based my solution on Distinct (see MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)). The way I generate the hash is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4630550/203371) neat approach which uses an anonymous type e.g.

```
public int GetHashCode(SomeType sometype)
{
 //Calculate the hash code for the SomeType.
 return new { sometype.Application, sometype.ExternalID }.GetHashCode();
}
```

To achieve the correct desired results a combination of grouping, ordering and use of distinct needs to be applied e.g.

```
    var noduplicates = products.GroupBy(x => new {x.Application, x.ExternalDisplayId})
        .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).First())
        .ToList()
        .Distinct(new ApplicationExternalDisplayIdComparer())
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.Application, x.ExternalID})
        .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).First())
        .ToList()
        .Distinct(new ApplicationExternalIDComparer());
```

As you'll see in the fiddle output, this gives the results you are expecting.

Comment: Why do you think that my answer does not sort the objects correctly? Can you please explain?

Comment: Hi Yacoub. I implemented the solution in the same way as you, but I found that simply ordering the dates prior to executing the distinct statements wont give the OP's desired results. Try creating a .NET fiddle of your answer and use the OP's example data in his question, and you'll see that what you have wont give his expected results.

Comment: Hello Ben. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xSkjaS) it is. It gives the same results.

Comment: I thought the OP wants the results in the exact same order he specified in his question. To achieve that ordering you need to group, order by date and then apply distinct. I too had your result set which your fiddle gives but I thought the OP wanted the specified ordering; my answer gives the results in that order.

Comment: I see. It doesn't seem to me that OP has such requirement.

Comment: Regarding ordering, it seems to me that OP requirement is just to make sure that we don't remove the item with the most recent `CreatedDate`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he does as that's why he's also grouping and ordering his data. We'll find out when he gives us an update. Whatever, it's been an interesting question!

Comment: @YacoubMassad is right. I didn't have the requirement to have the filtered set to be ordered.

Comment: @melmack You say you didn't have a requirement, so why were you grouping and ordering in your question? Your desired result had a distinct ordering which can only be achieved if you grouped and ordered like in my answer i.e. the desired result set is not simply ordered by date descending.

Comment: @BenSmith - the main requirement was to remove duplicates. The secondary requirement was to only include the record that is the most recent - of each duplicate.